Does double stochastic integral have exponential moments?
Consider $W=(W_1,W_2):[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a planar Brownian motion, and $W'$ a second one, independent from the first.
Let
$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\log (|W-W'|^{-1}) \, \mathrm{d} W_1 \, \mathrm{d} {W_1}'$, where $\log_+$ is the positive part of the logarithm. Let also $J$ be the intersection local time between $W$ and $W'$ (formally $J= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \delta_{W_s,{W_t}'} \, \mathrm{d} s \, \mathrm{d} t$).
For which $\lambda\neq 0$ and $\mu\geq 0$ does
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \exp( \lambda I-\mu J)]<\infty?
$$
I'm interested with any proof that for some $\lambda,\mu$ this is finite, but also in any proof that for some $\lambda,\mu$ this is infinite. Note also $\mu$ here is supposed to help make the expectation finite.
Remark if you replace the $\log$ function with a bounded function, then you have finiteness for $\lambda$ small enough (and $\mu=0$).
